# applying cosine() to numbers in an array

Tags: arrays, numpy

I'm getting a different result trying to replace numbers in an array with the number's cosine depending what I do.

I have a 10 x 10 Numpy array and I'm trying to apply a cosine to the even columns.

This is my array

```
tens

array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18],
       [ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27],
       [ 0,  4,  8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36],
       [ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45],
       [ 0,  6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54],
       [ 0,  7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63],
       [ 0,  8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72],
       [ 0,  9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81]])
```

I rotate and slice the array to apply the cosine to the even columns and use the same slicing and rotating to store the cosine in the right position.

```
tens[:, 0::2] = np.cos(tens[:, 0::2])
```

Here is the array after that

```
tens

array([[ 1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  0,  3,  0,  5,  0,  7,  0,  9],
       [ 1,  2,  0,  6,  0, 10,  0, 14,  0, 18],
       [ 1,  3,  0,  9,  0, 15,  0, 21,  0, 27],
       [ 1,  4,  0, 12,  0, 20,  0, 28,  0, 36],
       [ 1,  5,  0, 15,  0, 25,  0, 35,  0, 45],
       [ 1,  6,  0, 18,  0, 30,  0, 42,  0, 54],
       [ 1,  7,  0, 21,  0, 35,  0, 49,  0, 63],
       [ 1,  8,  0, 24,  0, 40,  0, 56,  0, 72],
       [ 1,  9,  0, 27,  0, 45,  0, 63,  0, 81]])
```

I'm not sure why I get integers here instead of floats. I don't get this if I apply a cosine to the original array. I get this.

```
np.cos(tens[:, 1::2])  

array([[ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.54030231, -0.9899925 ,  0.28366219,  0.75390225, -0.91113026],
       [-0.41614684,  0.96017029, -0.83907153,  0.13673722,  0.66031671],
       [-0.9899925 , -0.91113026, -0.75968791, -0.54772926, -0.29213881],
       [-0.65364362,  0.84385396,  0.40808206, -0.96260587, -0.12796369],
       [ 0.28366219, -0.75968791,  0.99120281, -0.90369221,  0.52532199],
       [ 0.96017029,  0.66031671,  0.15425145, -0.39998531, -0.82930983],
       [ 0.75390225, -0.54772926, -0.90369221,  0.30059254,  0.98589658],
       [-0.14550003,  0.42417901, -0.66693806,  0.85322011, -0.96725059],
       [-0.91113026, -0.29213881,  0.52532199,  0.98589658,  0.77668598]])
```

Is there something happening with floats and integers when I try to store these numbers in their correct positions in the original array?

Comment: `tens` is an integer array; assigning floats to it doesn't change that.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Makes sense. If you want to write `tens = tens.astype(float)` as an answer I'll give you the green check.